# Mouseenter and AJAX Event - JQUERY

Tags: jquery

Hi I have problem with mouseenter and ajax trigger. I want to trigger the ajax if I have focused on the object like 1 second. If I left the object it should not trigger the ajax event.

```
$('.popHover').mouseenter(function(e){
    setTimeout(function(){
    // ajax event here and pophover will show
    },1000)
}).mouseout(function(e){
    // close pophover
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [clearTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.clearTimeout).

```
var timeout_id;

$('.popHover').mouseenter(function(e){
    timeout_id = setTimeout(function(){
    // ajax event here and pophover will show
    },1000);
}).mouseout(function(e){
    // close pophover
    clearTimeout(timeout_id);
});
```